# Running self suicide thread from event handler

Tags: c#, multithreading, event-handling, thread-safety

I am very new to multi threading and c#, I have to solve this probelm:
I have event handler which is fired pretty often (it must be done that way, because event handler calls are invoked from the dll)
When handler method is invoked, I need to create and run one thread which will do some stuff and its processing can vary from few millisconds to few seconds, when finishes its work it kills itself. When it's finished, evenhandler can create another thread. Meanwhile created thread is running, no other threads can be created and runned from eventhandler.

Many thanks for help.

Comment: What do you want to do when the event is raised when a previously created worker thread is still running? Block the thread raising the event until the worker thread is done? Queue the spawning of the new thread and return? Just decide not to spawn the new thread and return?

Comment: How do I check in the event handler whether the thread is already running, and make it thread safe? It seems pretty easy, just to skip creating new thread.

Answer (score 4):

This all sounds pretty complicated, and I don't have a good sense of what you're actually trying to do, but it sounds like this would be better handled with a *single* extra thread and a shared queue of work items. Your event handler would just add another work item to the queue, and the thread would pick items off the queue and process them one at a time.

.NET 4 makes this easy with the [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) type. Before .NET 4 it's still doable of course, but you'll need to find a third-party thread-safe producer/consumer queue or write one yourself.

Comment: I have closed dll, which is reading http stream and from time to time when it founds some data it fires eventhandler. I need to create the thread and pass those data to the thread for processing. Meanwhile dll thread is still running and reads the data from http and fires eventhandler, but I don't want to create new thread for data processing until that first thread is done.

Answer (score 0):

Threads that kill themselves present problems. You have to synchronise with the main thread when the thread does kill itself.

It sounds to me as though you would be better off with a single dedicated thread that did the work. Use a blocking queue and implement the producer/consumer pattern. Rather than kill the thread when it has nothing to do, let it sit idle until more work arrives.

Comment: hm that should work too, as I've written, I am very new to threading. I would appreciate some short example, especially how to detect if the thread is processing (skipping sending data to the thread in eventhandler).